# App engine task queue security context

Tags: java, google-app-engine, scheduled-tasks

I am investigating how to run background tasks in App Engine.
It seems that task queue is a good choice. But how does task queue deal with user login? My background task requires a user to be logged in.
My understanding is when task queue runs a task, it sends a HTTP quest to my app, but if all my resources are protected and requires a user context, how should I handle that?

Answer (score 2):

Task queues are allowed to use admin-only endpoints, so for example you can include a user ID in your task's payload, run it through an admin-only URL, then just trust that the user ID is correct when it runs.

This is explained in Google's documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#securing_task_handler_urls)

Answer (score 1):

Your servlet could rely on task queue specific headers (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#reading_request_headers). These are set internally by Google App Engine, so you can trust it.

Also you can use parameters (see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/push/example) to pass any data to queue task processor (user id, token etc.).